# Why doesn't my component know whether I loggined - Angular 7

Tags: angular

When I loggined, my navbar for the first time didn't recognize that, but when I refresh the page, it just knew. In this example, it didn't console.log ('Loggined') first until I refresh the page. Here are the code

---

app.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<section>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

---

nav.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

    if(this.auth.isLoggined()){
      console.log('Loggined')
    } 
}
```

---

auth.service.ts

```
  login(phone: string, pass: string){
    return this.http.post(this.server+'/user/login', {phoneNumber: phone, password: pass}, httpOptions)
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggined', 'false')
    localStorage.removeItem('userId')
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
    localStorage.removeItem('userTypeId')
    this.router.navigateByUrl('')
  }

  isLoggined(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('isLoggined') == 'true'){
      return true;
    }
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
login(){
    // Get phoneNumber and password
    const val = this.loginForm.value
    if(val.phoneNumber && val.password){
      this.auth.login(val.phoneNumber, val.password).subscribe(
        (next) => {
          console.log('User is login')
          // Get userId, token, userTypeId, save at localStorage
          this.user = next
          console.log(this.user)
          localStorage.setItem('userId', this.user.data.userId)
          localStorage.setItem('token', this.user.token)
          localStorage.setItem('userTypeId', this.user.data.userType.id)
          // Set isLoggined = true
          localStorage.setItem('isLoggined', 'true')
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/')

        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err)
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

English is not my mother language so if you feel hard to understand please ask me, Thanks

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with an asynchronous call to whatever your login end point is. This call probably does not correctly update the internal state of the running application in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

**nav.component.ts**

```
public isLoggedIn : boolean;
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.isLoggedIn$.subscribe((res: boolean) => {
        this.isLoggedIn = res;
    })

}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

public isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
login(phone: string, pass: string){
    return this.http.post(this.server + '/user/login', { phoneNumber: phone, password: pass }, httpOptions)
}

setLoggin (status: boolean): void {
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(status);
}
logout(){
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggined', 'false')
    localStorage.removeItem('userId')
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
    localStorage.removeItem('userTypeId')
    this.router.navigateByUrl('')

    // Set Login status False
    this.setLoggin(false);
}

isLoggined(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggined') == 'true') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Login.component.ts**

```
login(){
    // Get phoneNumber and password
    const val = this.loginForm.value
    if (val.phoneNumber && val.password) {
        this.auth.login(val.phoneNumber, val.password).subscribe(
            (next) => {
                // Set Login Status True
                this.auth.setLoggin(true);
                console.log('User is login')
                // Get userId, token, userTypeId, save at localStorage
                this.user = next
                console.log(this.user)
                localStorage.setItem('userId', this.user.data.userId)
                localStorage.setItem('token', this.user.token)
                localStorage.setItem('userTypeId', this.user.data.userType.id)
                // Set isLoggined = true
                localStorage.setItem('isLoggined', 'true')
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/')

            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

After `subscribing` the `isLoggedIn$` event. Every time status will change, changes will be reflected in `subscribed function`.

For more information:

[Behavior Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your auth.service.ts maybe have an event emitter that fires an event when someone is "loggined" then in your navbar component, you need to listen for this event. If you can post more of your code we can see what youre trying to do and where your problem is.

Comment: I just post some more code about login and logout stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

The point is my nav didn't recogize whether the user loggined until refresh the page. I think it's due to the navigate, so I change to use another syntax to redirect the page and it worked

login.component.ts

```
//login success, navigate to home page
      //this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
      window.location.href = '/';
```